# Teacher Assistant verbal job offer

Tags: job-offer

I received a verbal job offer today and accepted, cancelling 2 interviews. There is no letter of the job offer. I start tomorrow. Is a verbal job offer acceptable or should there be a letter?

Comment: If you found out _today_ and start _tomorrow_, they probably didn't have time for a letter. You should simply show up tomorrow as discussed, and it's likely everything will be sorted then.

Answer (score 2):

As has been indicated in comments, there's simply not enough time between acceptance and the job starting for you to receive a formal job offer in the mail and return it before you start.

Simply follow the instructions regarding starting work and go through the paperwork on arrival.

If you don't like what you hear when you're there, then head right out of the door again (in a polite fashion, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer, but verbal offer =/= signed contract. Unless you have one signed by both yourself and your employer, it can be rescinded.

At the end of the day, if you trust your employer, then it isn't an issue.